# Удаление адреса организации из поисковой выдачи Яндекса

Tags: seo, индексация, адрес

На html странице сайта присутствует два физических адреса организации. В поисковой выдаче Яндекса отображается описание, в котором закреплен только один из адресов, его номер телефона и кнопка для просмотра адреса в Яндекс.Картах.
Вопрос - как сделать, чтобы в поисковой выдаче отображались оба адреса, либо же убрать из выдачи тот адрес, который отображается? Благодарю.

Comment: написать письмо в поддержку Яндекса? Или выложить на сайте что то такое, что бы РосКомНадзор сам в Яндекс пришел и за Вас попросил

Comment: очень остроумно

Comment: Мне кажется, это очевидные варианты